# How To Disable Scrolling During Loading?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, preloader

I'm working on my personal website and have implemented a preloader.
After adding a second div to my website, I noticed I can scroll during the page loading. I dunno about you but I find that ugly and disturbing.

Here is a quick video. (I use chromeOS)

[Video](https://notdiamondz.github.io/images/Screen%20recording%202021-10-16%205.40.57%20PM.webm)

I really couldn't find anything on this because I think I was the only one with this problem. I'm not sure, however.

I used `$(window).on("load",function(){$(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");});` as well

Here is the code ([Github Repo](https://github.com/xItzDiamondx/xitzdiamondx.github.io))
Anyways, that's all I got.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions here cannot depend on 3rd party links to be answerable. Everything required to reproduce your problem needs to be included directly in your question in the form of a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add by default a class to your body the class should be as follows.

```
// CSS
.no-scroll {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```
<body class="no-scroll">
```

Once your script has completed or your function finishes you just call

```
document.body.classList.remove('no-scroll');
```

Make sure to add the following section at the end of your page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
   function onReady() {
     document.body.classList.remove('no-scroll');
   }
   
   if ( document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
      onReady();
   } else {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onReady);
   }
})();
</script>
```

Or you can do it with `jQuery`

```
// Make sure this code is the last piece of code in your HTML.
$(window).on("load", function() {
   document.body.classList.remove('no-scroll');
});
```

PS: Additionally to that consider the unlike scenario when someone does not have JavScript enabled so you add a default behavior. Take a look at `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: You told me to use what for recreating the site?

Comment: Something.js I forgot it